# Setting up emacs for haskell

Tags: haskell, emacs

Which emacs extensions do you use and how do you configure it to work productively?

P.S. I use haskell mode with additions of ghc-mod. I like it, but it doesn't support navigation to a symbol and completion doesn't look IDE-like but it's stil usable.

Comment: Voted to close: This isn't really a Q&A sort of question; too subjective. This is better suited as a /r/haskell self post or discussion on #haskell irc.

Comment: Chris Done has written a wiki for Emacs & Haskell mode : github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki and chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-mode-docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information at the [haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs).

Comment: I already red it and set up things which were usable.

Comment: Nope. Does it support anything ghc-mode doesn't support?

Comment: There is two experimental features documented, but I don't know whether these features will help you. Besides this, there isn't much activity in the commit logs on Scion project.

Answer (score 5):

Enable haskell support in auto-complete package - it will complete pragmas, function names, etc. haskell-mode also includes support for hlint & haskell scan - to check source code for "bad" code, etc.
There was work on Haskell support in CEDET, but it wasn't finished :-( Implementing of such support in CEDET will allow to get symbol navigation & code completion "automatically" as CEDET implements this out-of-box...